# ChromeDriver. Timed out connecting to Chrome. Linux debian server

Tags: java, linux, selenium, server, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Java application which uses ChromeDriver in --headless mode as WebDriver to parse site.

I use maven-assembly-plugin to assemble it into jar-with-dependencies. On my local debian machine the application starts and works perfectly. But when I try to start it on dedicated debian server without gui it gives me this:

```
$ java -jar parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d) on port 13694
Only local connections are allowed.
[1540730919.752][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540730923.752][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540730931.752][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540730947.753][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up.
[1540730949.758][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540730953.758][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540730961.758][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

I have chrome-stable, default-jdk and chromedriver installed on server so in theory it should work.

Here is code of WebDriver initialization

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1200x600");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

What is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: check your chromedriver path. It must be in "/usr/bin/chromedriver". And also check chrome driver version.

Comment: @Hiten I am guessing it could be related to a firewall or proxy issue.

Comment: @Bradz I tried to reset all iptables rules - still not works.
The path is correct. Version too

Comment: @Bradz Also if I wait long enough - there is this error:
`2018-10-29 16:35:18 ERROR Main:29 - org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: headless chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.05 seconds
...`

Comment: I found a way how to check chromedriver log. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/FewGm7j4

Comment: @SoulSoul Is it working fine without using `ChromeOptions` and `arguments`?

Comment: @Bradz It does not work any way neither with arguments or without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having same issue with Selenium Webdriver + Jmeter on Win 10 as shown below. It was security application "Sophos" on my system which was blocking it.

I fixed it by disabling the Security Application which is officially installed on my system. Its working fine now.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 46315
Only local connections are allowed.
[1540910061.181][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540910065.184][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540910073.193][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540910089.193][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up.
[1540910091.196][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540910095.196][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540910103.210][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1540910119.210][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up.
```

Make sure you dont have any security application installed which can block this program.

Comment: Thanks! I reinstalled system and now it works perfectly. Probably the problem was in some firewall or security configuration that I set up a year ago on that server.